# IIB 9 taking huge memory for the product feed flows

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

We have few product feeds flows which receives the data from data base. As soon as the data retrieved from the data base and store in Row variable the data flow engine consumes huge memory (consumes around 4GB of memory for 170 MB data). For understanding the problem we have created simple flow with MQInput node one compute node which returns the result set and stores it in Row variable. For this simple operation the memory consumption is 4.8GB and the actual data is 148 MB.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Hello. The memory usage depend on the parser you are using, so it might be 'normal' to have 4 GB of memory used even for a 170 MB message. Please note that IIB is not meant to handle large messages (by default, it requires fine tuning for htis) and 170 MB is definitely large. You can check about the special things to do to process large message (see : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.scenarios.doc/gop_03/topics/bj60043_.htm). If you can also provide the code behind and the transformation done, it might help (java, esql, mapping, ... xml, dfdl, ... ?)